# Custom "PrivateRoute" Component returning a React-Router Route || Redirect causes an Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following function as shown in React-Router Docs with the only exception is that I'm using a `prop` I pass to the component to check whether the user is authenticated or not:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return (
          props.isAuthenticated ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { from: props.location },
              }}
            />
          )
        );
      }
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Here's what's being rendered:

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    { isLoading ? (<SplashScreenView />) : (
      <Router>
        <ContentContext.Provider value={appContent}>
          <TitleBarRouter />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" render={props => <LoginView {...props} performAuthentication={this.performAuthentication} isAuthenticating={isAuthenticating} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" render={props => <MainView {...props} checked={appContent.checked} elapsed={elapsed} />} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/settings" component={SettingsView} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/card" component={CardView} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/memberships" component={ActiveMembershipsView} />
          </Switch>
          <TabBarRouter />
        </ContentContext.Provider>
      </Router>
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

And this is how I'm setting the state. This function is passed as prop to the `/login` route where it's called on a button click.

```
  performAuthentication(obj) {
    this.setState({
      isAuthenticating: true,
    }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          isAuthenticating: false,
          isAuthenticated: true,
        });
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
```

The error I'm getting when I set `isAuthenticated` to `true` and the `PrivateRoutes` are supposed to render is `Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded.` I managed to track it down to the `PrivateRoute` function which causes an infinite loop, which in turn should be causing the error. I can't for the life of me figure why this is happening though. I'd appreciate any pointers.